# What animal are these coffee-ground-like leavings around my doorframe from?

Tags: wood, door-frame, damage

We are finding strange stuff around the frame of our bathroom door. It looks almost like ground coffee, and has no discernible smell. It's getting out of hand: we cleaned it up yesterday and this much has showed up again today:

[image]

[image]

There is nothing above or around the frame where this could have come from: no holes or cracks.

Is this the work of some form of woodworm, termite, or some other animal?

We live in a hot, arid climate on the Canary Islands.

Comment: Brew up  cup and try it. MMMMM Termite dung coffee :)  ( Just a joke, do  not do that ).

Answer (score 5):

I'm not a pest control specialist but that's got insect written all over it, and given the proximity to that wooden architrave/post/whatever-it-is I'd be worried about termites or some other wood boring critter. Call an exterminator post haste.

Comment: I agree, that looks like dry-wood termite excrement. They make "dump holes" in the galleries they carve out while munching away at your woodwork. Zap em with Term-Out.

Comment: Definitely termites. Do a google image search for "termite excrement"

Answer (score 2):

Its termite droppings. No smell cuz it's pretty much sawdust

Comment: Carpenter ants are another possibility.